# Removing one or more than one specific languages from Google results

Tags: google-search

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove one or more than one specific languages from Google results. For example, here I want to exclude Spanish, I prefer only English and Italian:

https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C2GCEA_enIT819IT819&source=hp&ei=498dXeCIJ4iasAe4xKqQAg&q=linea+di+base+%22baseline+wander%22&oq=li&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.35i39l2j0i67l2j0l6.296.490..1949...0.0..0.106.231.2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0.7d1PQ1L83dI

In my language settings of Google Chrome, there are only English and Italian.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to **https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en-GB#languages** you can set it up the way you wish:

[image: 0]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello @user0, in the above link you can select only one language; in my case english is selected by default...but, if you write in google chrome english and italian words, you get results in english, italian and other languages as you can see by clicking on the above link in my question.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi answer updated. this is the only way how to control the language output. there is no URL parameter nor search parameter for language restriction

Comment: after changing the settings you suggested me, unfortunately the situation is the same. Anyway, thank you for your help.